# CSS: line-break doesn't work with too long line

Tags: css

Here is the problem that I'm suffering:
The normal view of my page should look like:
[image]

However, sometimes the content is too long, turn the page into this:
[image]

HTML is just:

```
<p>[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/223450967"....</p>
```

I think the reason is that the line is too long. (`url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/223450967"`). How can I do it?

=============

What I have tried:

1. `P{word-wrap: break-word;}` . It didn't work.
2. `overflow: hidden`, didn't work. And I don't want `fixed width`, because I want responsiveness.

I think the problem maybe that the `outer div`'s width get expanded according to the content?

Addtionally, the page appreas normal in `Desktop Firefox`, but wrong under desktop `Chrome iPhone emulation dev mode`:

[image]

And You can visit `http://productchaseapp.herokuapp.com/articles/list?date=2015-08-21&page=4&range=week&sort=new` to see the effect, just make sure you're using mobile emulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first option is the `word-break`property

```
p {
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

But this will break up all words at the end of a line, so unless you selectively apply it to URLs...

Your better option is the following.

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This works as expected, but requires that you change some other CSS for the non-mobile layout as `table-layout: fixed` is a pretty significant change.

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` will break any word as soon as it hits boundary. This is not ideal for this use case. [Case in point](http://imgur.com/LLFaB5l)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `word-wrap: break-word;` didn't work is because it will only wrap when its container enforces an explicit width. As an experiment, take that `p` and give it `display: block; width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word;` now it works! But you probably don't want to explicitly set a `px` width and you are probably wondering how it's not working, because you set `width: 100%;` on its parent container. Well, the reason is because you used `table` layout, which attempts to adjust its width based on its contents by default. On your `table` element, give it `table-layout: fixed;` that will do the trick. https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

FYI, `word-wrap` is renamed to `overflow-wrap` in the latest standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap See Note.

Comment: Thanks enormously, I didn't thought it could get this complicated